# CSS nth image x transform

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a small game, for which I use point icons. These icons should be partly overlaid on top of each other.

Right now, I am doing this:

```
.wormicon:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.wormicon:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.wormicon:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateX(-150%);
}
```

which works but feels inelegant; is there a better solution in straight CSS?

The second part of my question is related to the extra space that comes from these translations: how do I get rid of the extraneous width? (i.e. 50% of one icon for two images, 100% for three images etc.)

Here is an image depicting the issue: [image: worms -- too much space on the right]

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something like Zurfyx :**

```css
.wormicon {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.wormicon:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="what_ever_element_here">
  <img class="wormicon" src="http://www.irrawaddy.com/wp-content/themes/irrawaddy-skin/images/icon/loved.svg">
  <img class="wormicon" src="http://www.irrawaddy.com/wp-content/themes/irrawaddy-skin/images/icon/loved.svg">
  <img class="wormicon" src="http://www.irrawaddy.com/wp-content/themes/irrawaddy-skin/images/icon/loved.svg">
  <img class="wormicon" src="http://www.irrawaddy.com/wp-content/themes/irrawaddy-skin/images/icon/loved.svg">
  <div class="what_ever_element_here">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `margin-left` with negative values on the whole images group.

```
.container > img {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/new-york-apple-symbol_318-68820.jpg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/new-york-apple-symbol_318-68820.jpg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/new-york-apple-symbol_318-68820.jpg">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/new-york-apple-symbol_318-68820.jpg">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the second answer which I found simpler